# R: Define column name with paste()

Tags: r, dataframe

The question is pretty simple but I couldn't find a solution.

I want to create a new dataframe defining the name of the column with `paste0`.

Ideally I would like to do something like this (which of doesn't work).

```
mydataframe <- data.frame(id = 1,
                          paste0('Here_','my_','column_','name') = 'foo')
# Error: unexpected '=' in:
#   "mydataframe <- data.frame(id = 1,
#                           paste0('Here_','my_','column_','name') ="
```

Also, why doesn't work?

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you are trying to do.  Is this example showing a single data frame, with a single variable that contains a single value?

Comment: @BrianP I think what he wants is to be able to dynamically specify the  name associated with the column vector `'foo'`, so the result would be equivalent to manually typing `data.frame(id = 1, Here_my_column_name = 'foo')`.

Answer (score 8):

`Data.frame` is a function, and therefore takes arguments.  These arguments cannot be other functions.  For example, you could not define a function like `fn <- function(paste0('Hi_', 'how_are_you') = x) { x }`.  R just doesn't work that way.

However, you still can dynamically change your column names after the fact:

```
df <- data.frame(1, 'foo')
names(df) <- c('id', paste0('Here_','my_','column_','name'))
```

That should do what you want.

Bonus: You can simplify your paste as follows: `paste('Here', 'my', 'column', 'name', sep = '_')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
df[, paste('Here', 'my', 'column', 'name', sep = '_')] <- 'foo'
```

It is impossible to do it as you suggest, because no variable is evaluated, it just gets exactly what you are writing and trying to use it as a name for the column. This way, `paste('Here', 'my', 'column', 'name', sep = '_')` gets evaluated and the returned string is actually used as a name for the column.

Answer (score 1):

I needed the same some time ago and solved the problem with putting all the command inside paste function with following evaluation

```
i=3
mydf <- eval(parse(text = paste0(
  "data.frame( id =", 1, ", my_col", i, "=", 55, ")")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setNames` to *define column names of a `data.frame` with paste()* - *dynamically specify the column name*

```
setNames(data.frame(1, 'foo'), c("id",  paste0('Here_','my_','column_','name')))
#  id Here_my_column_name
#1  1                 foo
```